# SQL: joining view to table for query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

[image: screenshot error message here]

```
SELECT January.customer_id as Jancust_id,
           SUM(payments.payment) as Jan_cust_pmts,
           COUNT(DISTINCT January.customer_id) AS Jan_orig_cust,
           COUNT(DISTINCT payments.customer_id) as Jan_ret_cust,
           AVG(payments.payment) as Cust_life_rev
           January.acquisition_source as Jan_source
    FROM January_Cohort January
    LEFT JOIN telemon_payments_data payments
    ON January.customer_id = payments.customer_id
    GROUP BY Jan_source
```

So the above is supposed to be a query where January_Cohort is a view that was already made, and I'm wanted to join it to a table telemon_payments_data.

**Am I referring to it wrong, or can I not join a table and a view?**
The error message is saying January_Cohort is not a table; which I know, it's a view.

Answer (score 0):

may be it will work 
make view as sub-query table

```
SELECT January.customer_id as Jancust_id,
           SUM(payments.payment) as Jan_cust_pmts,
           COUNT(DISTINCT January.customer_id) AS Jan_orig_cust,
           COUNT(DISTINCT payments.customer_id) as Jan_ret_cust,
           AVG(payments.payment) as Cust_life_rev
           January.acquisition_source as Jan_source
    FROM (select * from January_Cohort) January
    LEFT JOIN telemon_payments_data payments
    ON January.customer_id = payments.customer_id
    GROUP BY Jan_source
```